# Search and group from logfile

Tags: powershell, full-text-search, grouping, logfile-analysis

I have a logfile with many entries. Some of them begin with a date, some others not.
I want to search for all entries from this/last month with 
`"UpgradeResource] part: 3-V12345678-12-"` in the line and count the results grouped by box. 
Actually there are 9 boxes counting from 1 to 9 but if we buy another box there will be a 10 or 11… the box-counter is always followed by -1 at the end of the line.

The lines I search for look like this:

```
2016-04-27 11:49:43,895 INFO  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-9] [com.xxx.shared.yyy.UpgradeResource] part: 3-V12345678-12-5-245, box: 3-V12345678-38-3-1
...
2016-04-27 11:49:43,895 INFO  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-9][com.xxx.shared.yyy.UpgradeResource] part: 3-V12345678-12-4-112, box: 3-V12345678-38-1-1
```

My result-output should be:

```
Month 03/2016:
Box 1: 10 times
Box 2: 123 times
Box 3: 65 times

Month 04/2016:
Box 1: 75 times
Box 2: 13 times
Box 3: 147 times
```

I am not very firm in using powershell and tried this but get errors and think I am not on the right way:

```
$inputfile = "C:\temp\result.txt"
$matchstring = "(?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*UpgradeResource] part: 3-V12345678-12-(?.*?), box: 3-V12345678-38-(\d{1})-1"
Get-Content $inputfile | foreach { 
    if ($_ -match $matchstring) {
        "" | select @{n='Date';e={$matches.date}},@{n='Key';e={$matches.Key}},@{n='PD';e={$matches.PD}}
    }
}
```

The Error I get:

```
"(?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*UpgradeResource] part:
3-V12345678-12-(?.*?), box: 3-V1001686-38-(\d{1})-1" wird analysiert -
Unbekanntes Gruppierungskonstrukt.
In C:\temp\count.ps1:16 Zeichen:6
+ if ($_ -match $matchstring)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Comment: You can test your regex in a tool like https://regex101.com/ . There are some `?`in your matchstring, which are not accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is because `(?...)` is not a valid grouping construct. If you want to use named groups (which the rest of your code suggests) the question mark must be followed by the group name in angular brackets (`(?<name>...)`). For a non-capturing group it must be followed by a colon (`(?:...)`).

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further information.

Your code should probably look somewhat like this:

```
$inputfile   = 'C:\temp\result.txt'
$matchstring = '(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})' +
               '.*UpgradeResource] ' +
               'part: 3-V12345678-12-(?<Key>.*?), ' +
               'box: 3-V12345678-38-(?<PD>\d{1})-1'
Get-Content $inputfile | Where-Object {
  $_ -match $matchstring
} | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property  @{
    'Date' = $matches.date
    'Time' = $matches.time
    'Key'  = $matches.Key
    'Box'  = 'Box ' + $matches.PD
  }
} | Group-Object Date, Box
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that fit ?

```
$inputfile = "C:\temp\result.txt"
$matchstring = "(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*UpgradeResource] part: 3-V12345678-12-(.*), box: 3-V12345678-38-(\d{1})-1"

Get-Content $inputfile | foreach { 
if ($_ -match $matchstring) {

    "" | select @{n='Date';e={$matches.1}},@{n='Key';e={$matches.2}},@{n='PD';e={$matches.3}}
}
```

}

Gives me that Output:

```
Date                                                    Key                                                     PD                                                    
----                                                    ---                                                     --                                                    
2016-04-27 11:49:43                                     5-245                                                   3                                                     
2016-04-27 11:49:43                                     4-112                                                   1
```

Comment: Yes, this works. And now how do I count and group by PD? And how can I get results for this/last month grouped?

Comment: You can add an `| group pd` to the `""  | select ..`line for grouping by PD. Grouping by month requires a little more string operation, as a `group date` will group by exact date.

Comment: OK, I will try more things. I now have seen that there are many entries with the same timestamp. I need to find out, how I can count only one entry with the same timestamp.

Comment: You can break down the date, or just take the information `year-month` of it.